# Finding the position of Noun and Verb in a sentence Python

Tags: python, indexing, position, nltk, pos-tagger

Is there a way to find the position of the words with pos-tag 'NN' and 'VB' in a sentence in Python?

example of a sentences in a csv file:
"Man walks into a bar."
"Cop shoots his gun."
"Kid drives into a ditch"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find positions for certein PoS tags on a text using some of the existing NLP frameworks such us [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) or [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/). Once you process the text you can iterate for each token and check if the pos tag is what you are looking for, then get the start/end position of that token in your text.

**Spacy**

Using spacy, the code to implement what you want would be something like this:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
doc = nlp("Man walks into a bar.")  # Your text here

words = []
for token in doc:
    if token.pos_ == "NOUN" or token.pos_ == "VERB":
        start = token.idx  # Start position of token
        end = token.idx + len(token)  # End position = start + len(token)
        words.append((token.text, start, end, token.pos_))

print(words)
```

In short, I build a new document from the string, iterate over all the tokens and keep only those whose post tag is VERB or NOUN. Finally I add the token info to a list for further processing. I strongly recommend that you read the following [spacy tutorial](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101) for more information.

**NLTK**

Using NLTK I think is pretty straightforward too, using [NLTK tokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) and [pos tagger](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html). The rest is almost analogous to how we do it using spacy.

What I'm not sure about is the most correct way to get the start-end positions of each token. Note that for this I am using a tokenization helper created by `WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize()` method, which returns a list of tuples with the start and end positions of each token. Maybe there is a simpler and NLTK-like way of doing it.

```py
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer

text = "Man walks into a bar."  # Your text here
tokens_positions = list(WhitespaceTokenizer().span_tokenize(text))  # Tokenize to spans to get start/end positions: [(0, 3), (4, 9), ... ]
tokens = WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(text)  # Tokenize on a string lists: ["man", "walks", "into", ... ]

tokens = nltk.pos_tag(tokens) # Run Part-of-Speech tager

# Iterate on each token
words = []
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    text, tag = tokens[i]  # Get tag
    start, end = tokens_positions[i]  # Get token start/end
    if tag == "NN" or tag == "VBZ":
        words.append((start, end, tag))

print(words)
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful, but what if I want to use a csv files then contains more than 1 sentences instead of assigning a sentence to text?

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your original question with code and example of what do you expect? I guess if you have a CSV file with multiple lines and you expect to have a result for each line you can process each line separately inside a for loop... So please give me more information so I can help you

Comment: Sorry for the vague questions with little to none information. But here is a question i asked which might be clearer - https://stackoverflow.com/q/71417857/17973460

Answer (score 3):

you should take a look at [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html).

From the doc:

```
import nltk
text = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("They refuse to permit us to obtain the refuse permit")


nltk.pos_tag(text)

[('They', 'PRP'), ('refuse', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('permit', 'VB'), ('us', 'PRP'),
('to', 'TO'), ('obtain', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('refuse', 'NN'), ('permit', 'NN')]
```

Comment: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html