# Position of that Noun and Verb

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I have a rule-based code that prints out the Noun which is followed by a verb in a sentence

```
for text_id, text in enumerate(news_df['news_title'].values):
    
    # Remove the comma and full stops
    text = text.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('-','')
    sentence_tags = POSTAG(text.lower())
    
    print(text)
    
    # Sentences parts
    for index, part in enumerate(sentence_tags):
        try:
            
            if 'NN' in part[1] and 'VB' in sentence_tags[index + 1][1]:
            print(">", part[0])
            break
            
        elif 'NN' in part[1] and 'NN' in sentence_tags[index + 1][1] and 'VB' in sentence_tags[index + 2][1]:
            print(">", part[0],  sentence_tags[index + 1][0])
            break
            
        elif 'NN' in part[1] and 'NN' in sentence_tags[index + 1][1] and 'NN' in sentence_tags[index + 2][1] and 'VB' in sentence_tags[index + 3][1]:
            print(">", part[0],  sentence_tags[index + 1][0], sentence_tags[index + 2][0])
            break

        except:
            pass
    print()
```

The output of a sentence following this rule:

high school football players charged after video surfaces showing hazing

```
> school football players
```

trump accuser pushes new york to pass the adult survivors act plans to sue

```
>trump accuser
```

Is there a way to also print out the position of that Noun that was printed due to the rule?
for example :

```
>trump accuser , [0,5,"NN"] , [6,13,"VB"]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) what kind of POS tagger you're using? `Spacy`, `NLTK` or ...

Comment: Thank you @meti ! , for this i am using NLTK :D

Comment: @meti Is there a way for this using either NLTK or Spacy?

Comment: I'll come up with an answer ASAP, It might be necessary for me to change your script :( @Beginner

Comment: @meti Your answer have been very helpful! Is there also a way to find the distance of the Noun from the verb? in cases where my rule I made does not apply to the sentence so in some cases where the Noun will be followed by adj then a Verb..

Comment: Definitely, it is. Are you familiar with the State machine and its implementation? @Beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the script and separated the `state machine` segment. The most serious problem with this program IMO is it's just returning the first pattern (you can fix it quickly).

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
POSTAG = nltk.pos_tag
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['high school football players charged after video surfaces showing hazing', 'trump accuser pushes new york to pass the adult survivors act plans to sue']})
for text_id, text in enumerate(df['text'].values):
    
    # Remove the comma and full stops
    text = text.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('-','')
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower())
    sentence_tags = POSTAG(tokens)
    words = [item[0] for item in sentence_tags]
    start_end = []
    temp = 0
    for word in words:
      start_end.append([temp, temp+len(word)])
      temp+= (len(word)+1) 
    tags = [item[1] for item in sentence_tags]
    words_to_print = []
    tags_to_print = []
    start_end_to_print = []
    # the state machine 
    verb = False
    first_noun = False
    second_noun = False
    third_noun = False
    for w, t, se in zip(words, tags, start_end):
      if t.startswith('NN'):
        words_to_print.append(w)
        tags_to_print.append(t)
        start_end_to_print.append(se)
        first_noun = True

      elif t.startswith('NN') and first_noun:
        words_to_print.append(w)
        tags_to_print.append(t)
        start_end_to_print.append(se)
        second_noun = True

      elif t.startswith('NN') and second_noun:
        words_to_print.append(w)
        tags_to_print.append(t)
        start_end_to_print.append(se)
        third_noun = True

      elif t.startswith('VB') and (first_noun or second_noun or third_noun):
        break 
      
      elif (first_noun or second_noun or third_noun):
        words_to_print = []
        tags_to_print = []
        start_end_to_print = []
        verb = False
        first_noun, second_noun, third_noun = False, False, False
    
    print('> ', ' '.join(words_to_print), ' '.join([str(item[0])+' '+str(item[1]) for item in zip(start_end_to_print, tags_to_print)]))
```

output:

```
>  school football players [5, 11] NN [12, 20] NN [21, 28] NNS
>  trump accuser [0, 5] NN [6, 13] NN
```